# Python queue(s) and threads, mixing datas into one queue for different tasks?

Tags: python, multithreading

What's best practice for dealing with queue(s) with different kind of data, each for a different consumer ?

Shall I get one queue per type of data, or line-up all data in the same queue and send each item to it's associated consumer ?

For the later, I ended up with this code `creator` sends data to the queue for `consumer1` or `consumer2` to process. It works as it has only two consumers, but is highly inefficient as it goes most of the time to the wrong consumer, then back into the queue, until the right consumer gets it.

```
import threading
import time
import random
from queue import Queue


def creator(q):
    """Creates data to be consumed by consumers 1 or 2"""

    while True:
        # Simulates new data coming at random intervals
        data = random.randint(2, 5)
        time.sleep(data)

        # Send this data to the queue for consumer 1 or 2 randomly
        to_consumer = random.randint(1, 2)
        print('New data available for consumer ', to_consumer)
        q.put((to_consumer, data))


def my_consumer1(q):
    """Consumes some data and works on it"""
    while True:
        to_consumer, data = q.get()
        if to_consumer == 1:
            # Process message if correct consumer
            print('Consumer 1 received the data : {}'.format(data))
            q.task_done()
        else:
            # Or put it back into the queue
            q.put((to_consumer, data))


def my_consumer2(q):
    """Consumes some data and works on it"""
    while True:
        to_consumer, data = q.get()
        if to_consumer == 2:
            # Process message if correct consumer
            print('Consumer 2 received the data : {}'.format(data))
            q.task_done()
        else:
            # Or put it back into the queue
            q.put((to_consumer, data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()

    thread_one = threading.Thread(target=creator, args=(q,))
    thread_two = threading.Thread(target=my_consumer1, args=(q,))
    thread_three = threading.Thread(target=my_consumer2, args=(q,))
    thread_one.start()
    thread_two.start()
    thread_three.start()

    q.join()
```

Comment: Putting everything into one queue like that is very inefficient. Give each consumer its own queue!

Comment: If you want to use one thread per consumer you should also create one queue per consumer.

Comment: To be more accurate: one Queue per type of consumer, where every type can run multiple times as separate threads.